# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'board')

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, this, onmouseup

I try to use canvas as a clickable board for minesweeper. My problem is that i can clicked out of the canvas but i don't want to it. Here's my code:

```js
var board;
var ctx;
var bombs = [];
var clickedX;
var clickedY;

function initBoard(w, h){
 board = document.getElementById("board");
 ctx = board.getContext('2d');
 drawBoard(w,h);
 placedBombs();
}

function drawBoard(w,h){ 
 board.squareSize = {
  w: board.width / w, 
  h: board.height / h
 };
 
 ctx.fillStyle = "#C0C0C0"
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, board.width, board.height)

 board.drawGrid = function () {
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0; i <= w; i++) {
   ctx.moveTo(i * this.squareSize.w, 0);
   ctx.lineTo(i * this.squareSize.w, this.height);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= h; i++) {
   ctx.moveTo(0, i * this.squareSize.h);
   ctx.lineTo(this.width, i * this.squareSize.h);
  }
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.3;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
 }
 
 board.drawGrid(); 
}

function placedBombs(){
 for(var n=0; n<10; n++){
  bombs[n] = ([Math.floor(Math.random() * 10), Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)]);
 } 
}

board.onmouseup = function(e){
 board.squareSize = {
  w: board.width / 10, 
  h: board.height / 10
 };

 board.eventToGrid = function (e) {  
  return {    
   i: parseInt(e.offsetX / this.squareSize.w), 
   j: parseInt(e.offsetY / this.squareSize.h)
  };  
 } 
 var pos = board.eventToGrid(e);
 clickedX = pos.i;
 clickedY = pos.j;
 loc = document.getElementById("loc");
 loc.innerHTML = "Position: " + pos.i + ", " + pos.j;
 if(check(clickedX, clickedY) == false){
  lose();
 }
 /*else{
  clickPass(); 
 }*/
}
function check(clickedX, clickedY){
 console.log(clickedX);
 console.log(clickedY); 
 for(var i=0; i<bombs.length; i++){
  if((clickedX == bombs[i][0]) && (clickedY == bombs[i][1])){ 
   return false;
  }
 }
 return true; 
}

/*function clickPass(){
 
}*/
 
function lose(){
 alert("bomb");
}
```

```html
<body onload="initBoard(10,10)">
  <canvas id="board" width="350" height="350">
  </canvas>
  <div id="loc">
    Mouse location: x, y
  </div>
</body>
```

I try to use board as an object. But i failed.
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Where is the error happening?

Comment: If `board` is undefined, something may be preventing `initBoard` from running.

Comment: Sorry, i edit it now. board.onmouseup is my problem when i changed it this.onmouseup i clicked everywhere. When i used like this i have an error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'board')`

Comment: You're assigning to `board.onmouseup` before you've called `initBoard()`, so `board` hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the assignment to `board.onmouseup` inside `initBoard()`, so that it runs after you've assigned the variable.

```
function initBoard(w, h){
    board = document.getElementById("board");
    ctx = board.getContext('2d');
    drawBoard(w,h);
    placedBombs();
    board.onmouseup = function(e){
        board.squareSize = {
            w: board.width / 10, 
            h: board.height / 10
        };

        board.eventToGrid = function (e) {      
            return {            
                i: parseInt(e.offsetX / this.squareSize.w), 
                j: parseInt(e.offsetY / this.squareSize.h)
            };      
        }   
        var pos = board.eventToGrid(e);
        clickedX = pos.i;
        clickedY = pos.j;
        loc = document.getElementById("loc");
        loc.innerHTML = "Position: " + pos.i + ", " + pos.j;
        if(check(clickedX, clickedY) == false){
            lose();
        }
        /*else{
            clickPass();    
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working. Thank you. Can i use it out of the `initBoard()` function? Do you have any idea?

Comment: You could put it in another function, and use `<body onload="initBoard(); otherFunction();">`

Comment: The point is that you have to do it after the variable is assigned. There are many ways to accomplish that.